# ArrayList add method error

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is the piece of code

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Monkey");
```

Eclipse says:

Multiple markers at this line

- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
- Syntax error on token ""Monkey"", delete this token

I wasted about an hour trying to understand what is wrong.
This situation makes me hate java.

Comment: Post the complete code to reproduce the problems.

Comment: The problem is not with java. Even LISP will whine if you leave out a paren. This comes with being a programmer.

Comment: It may be that a set of {} or similar are wrong earlier on and this is the first point at which java knew there was something wrong for certain

Comment: *"This situation makes me hate java."* - Smile and Java will smile back.

Comment: Also; I found Java ridiculously hard and frustrating and then overnight it became awesome. Stick with it, it's difficult but worth it - In part because it pulls this sort of thing whereas other languages might just happily run (perhaps for several minutes) before getting to this line **then** get upset and crash (I'm looking at you matlab)

Comment: The line itself does not seem like a problem, post the surrounding lines too to see if there is any missing `(` or `{`, for example.

Comment: The problem is not the programming language but that some compilers are not good at giving helpful error messages. But often the problem is also the programmer not reading the error message. E.g. “misplaced construct(s)” says a lot. It says that it is not the construct itself which is wrong, so posting the construct alone won’t help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you have placed your code outside of a method or class. Try the following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public Test() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Monkey");
    }
}
```

Comment: I had this thought but on testing you get different errors for that, either "Class enum or interface expected" or "package list does not exist" depending on how far outside the method you use this code

Comment: The fact your posted code compiles doesn't mean is an explanation to solve OP's problem. Also, is not a good example to initialize a list in the class constructor just to prove *it works*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: True to both. However, the comment above the code is what gives it relevance. I have seen something very similar to the OP's error before. The question was not about code style but rather about basic syntax.

Comment: The error is about where this code is (mis)placed. That's why I ask OP to provide his/her code to give an accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed that stupid mistake/